# Debo mostrar el resultado de una consulta Mysql en PHP - resultado NaN

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una consultado ejecutada en mysql para contar el rango de inscritos a un sistema de gimnasio durante los últimos 30 días,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi código PHP tengo la consulta escrita de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
                                    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'gimnasio');
                                    $sql = "SELECT count(*) from american_sport 
                                    where fecha_ingreso between curdate() - interval 30 day and curdate()";
                                    if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
                                        $rowcount = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                                        echo "
                                        <h3 class='arlo_tm_counter' data-from='0' data-to=" . $rowcount . " data-speed='2000'>0</h3>
                                        <span>Total de Inscritos Nuevos</span>
                                        ";
                                    }
                                    
                                    ?>
```

Y el problema esta en que en el sistema el resultado me lo muestra como NaN,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde podría estar el problema?;

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aplica al metodo mysqli_fetch_array un segundo parametro, que es la propiedad MYSQLI_NUM `$rowcount = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);`  y en la impresion, osea en la etiqueta  especifica la posicion del array que recibes como respuesta, como la sentencia SQL es un COUNT se aplicaria en la posicion 0 asi. `$rowcount[0]`, ya que recuerda que la respuesta que recibes la guardas como un array.
Puedes revisar mas informacion en la documentacion oficial de php, https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php o aqui otro que habla de lo mismo https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

Comment: puedes revisar mas informacion en la documentacion oficial de php, https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php o aqui otro que habla de lo mismo https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero mejor agrega tu comentario a la pregunta pulsando sobre [edit] y quedará mejor :-)

Comment: okey, entiendo.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias por contribuir con buenas respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

**NaN** es un valor devuelto normalmente por javascript cuando no consigue o sabe interpretar un supuesto número.  Y no has puesto nada de código javascript en tu pregunta.

Tal como dicen en [esta página](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) donde definen lo que es **NaN**:

> La propiedad global NaN es un valor que representa Not-A-Number.

Revisa en tu código javascript cómo intentas cambiar el `0` devuelto en el PHP/MySQL dentro del **H3**, pues veo que usas atributos `data-from` y `data-to` que algun código en javascript debe leer e interpretar para mostrar el `Total de Inscritos Nuevos` esperado, en lugar del `0` que devuelves con el PHP/MySQL en esta línea:

```
<h3 class='arlo_tm_counter' data-from='0' data-to=" . $rowcount . " data-speed='2000'>0</h3>
```

Comment: Ese codigo es de un javascript que hace que el numero vaya del 0 hasta el numero total del contdown, deje el span como: <span>Total de Inscritos Nuevos " . $rowcount . "</span> y el resultado es "Array", no muestra el resultado en numero

Comment: Ok, me llego tarde el comentario. @Gabriel ya te ha dado una solución buena :-)